# Dynamicly generating level and placing obstacles Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, game-engine

So in my game i want to make tunel which is made of five walls, and each wall can be moved, but they are connected with joints. I want the level to be infinite, but I dont know how to exactly do it. I suppose the best way is to add another parts of the tunel as the player moves forward, but it would be nice if someone more experienced helped me. The other thing is placing obstacles on the walls(planes) randomly. Is there way to place the obstacle as a child of the wall to be relative to it( (0, 0, 0) is in the center of the wall)? If I didn't explain everything clearly enough let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course it is possible. For example your might simply have 3 tunnel segments:

```
   (P)
1 - 2 - 3
```

where the player is in segment 2. If they move forward into 3, you would simply cut 1 off the end and attach a new segment 4 after 3.

```
       (P)
    2 - 3 - 4
```

Of course you can do the same when the player moves back from 3 to 2, just cut 4 off again and attach 1 to 2.

Your segments can all be identical or completely different, that's up to you. You can still have variations, even if the segments are identical. They might have placeholders for random decorations, or item spawns, monster spawns, whatever. Whether those placeholders are actually filled can be decided by a formular which is guaranteed to be random while still always return the same result for a particular placeholder in a particular segment:

Assume all segments are identical and have 5 placeholders that can spawn anything from decoration (1), item (2), monster (3) or nothing (0). Your formula to decide what will be spawned might look like this:

```
int GetPlaceholderContent(int segment, int placeholder)
{
    System.Random random = new System.Random(segment * 1024 + placeholder);
    return random.Next(0, 4);
}

void FillPlaceholder(int segment, int placeholder)
{
    switch (GetPlaceholderContent(segment, placeholder))
    {
        case 0: /* FillWithNothing */ break;
        case 1: /* FillWithDecoration */ break;
        case 2: /* FillWithItem */ break;
        case 3: /* FillWithMonster */ break;
    }
}
```

Hope this gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpfull! I have only one doubt: for adding and romoving tunel segments should I make controller script which will do this? Is this the best option? I ales heard about some problems with placing stuff to far away from the (0, 0, 0) position. Is this real problem and should i reposition everything after some distance?

Comment: Depending on how fast you travel this can be a problem. Vector3 uses floats to store positions, so at a certain distance from 0 there will be inaccuracies. Float has a precision of 7 digits, so if your positions reach a distance between 100,000 to 999,999 units, you'll only have a precision of 0.1 units left. However, anything below 10,000 should be fine. If this really is a problem you can still warp the player back to 0 once he reaches a certain distance.

And yes, a level controller script might be a good idea: A centralized authority which manages spawning and despawning of segments.